# Handling of middle-mouse click

Tags: windows, winapi

In many Windiows applications (notepad, console window, Internet Explorer, Word) clicking on the middle mouse (or the scroll wheel) creates an overlay “compass” and allows fast scrolling in any direction.

How do I get this behavior in my application?  Is there an API, style or message that makes this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking is part of the `IntelliMouse` support, as far i know there is not a direct winapi to implement this functionality. but you can create your own.

check this article for a sample.

[`The Ultimate Toolbox Intellimouse Classes`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/MFC/UltimateToolbox_Mouse.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645610(v=VS.85).aspx . You can capture the WM_MBUTTONDOWN event in your message loop.  Also, see [middle-button scrolly thing in textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528934/middle-button-scrolly-thing-in-textbox).

Comment: It is the second one I want, but my window is not a textbox.  And I did try to call DefWindowProc for WM_MBUTTONDOWN, but that did not work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I think it is a reference to 'scrollwheel' 'centrebutton' 'panbutton' or similar value or argument in the call parameters to the mouse control routine. My mouse has the same facility by me pressing down the centre scroll wheel and then when finished pressing it again to return to normal scroll mode. Instead of a Windows call it would be better to use the call style of the language or package script in use for developing the code and the function would be activated by resolving the code to the hardware interface at compile, JIT or virtual machine runtime.