# AS3 - Drag to scroll ScrollPane with middle/right button

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse, drag, scrollpane

I know that it's possible to let the user drag the content in a `ScrollPane` around using `scrollDrag`, so that they don't have to use the scrollbars. However, with `scrollDrag`, it only works for the left mouse button.
What I want to be able to do is pretty much the same, but for either the middle (mousewheel) or right mouse button. That way the user can use the left button for other functions.

Does anybody know of a feature I may have missed that can do this, or a custom method? Note that I don't want [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253041/middle-button-click-to-scroll), I just want `scrollDrag` with other mouse buttons.

Comment: Then your question is really - Can I capture other than left mouse button clicks? The docs shows the MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN and MouseEvent.MIDDLE_MOUSE_DOWN so maybe you can listen for those events and do dragging in response to them.

Comment: Not necessarily. The `ScrollPane.scrollDrag` property is a property that can do the dragging automatically for you, but only for the left mouse click. I know that I can use event listeners to listen to events of the other mouse buttons and drag it like that, but I want to know if that's necessary or not. And if it is, maybe someone has some code I can use instead of me having to make my (probably buggy) own.